# What does a "double eigenvalue" mean in the context of a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> \begin{gathered}
> -v_{x x}=\lambda v \quad \text { for } 0<x<l \\
> v_{x}(0)=v_{x}(l)=\frac{v(l)-v(0)}{l}
> \end{gathered}

> Show that $\lambda=0$ is a double eigenvalue.

What does a "double eigenvalue mean?"

Comment: Have you studied [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory), which casts certain second order ordinary differential equations as linear operators and studies those equations using the theory of linear algebra?

Comment: The a "double eigenvalue" is an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity two.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Matrix_examples) and search for "Matrix with repeated eigenvalues example".